# reading values from the text file and defining the variables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a text file that contain string, floating point numbers, integers and separated with double space

cat input.txt

```
nms   val   pet  dzl
sdt   2.5   3.5   1
tyu   2.8   7.5   5
```

I want to load the txt file and want to define every rows values to the new variable inorder to perform some task inside the loop

My trial script

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
main_file=np.loadtxt("input.txt")
for file in main_file:
    a= should be sdt
    b= should be 2.5
    c= should be 3.5
    d= should be 1
```

similarly for second row i want to do the same so that

```
    a= should be tyu
    b= should be 2.8
    c= should be 7.5
    d= should be 5
```

Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'sdt'
How can I fix this.

Comment: Where does the error appear? Is it in the line with `main_file=np.loadtxt("input.txt")`? Here can you find a guide [how to read a file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/) in python with `readlines()`.

Comment: @mosc9575 it doesnot load the file at all

Comment: A starting point would be to read the `loadtxt` docs!  Second, when asking about an error, show the full error message.  My guess it occurs in `loadtxt`, and is the result of trying to convert strings like `std` into a float.  You didn't the docs, so did call `loadtxt` correctly for this file.

Comment: Since you are importing `pandas`, why not use its own `csv` reader?

Comment: @hpaulj If possible please suggest a solution using pandas or numpy its easier

Comment: Have you found the documentation for `loadtxt`?  This isn't a handholding service.  We expect you to do some digging.

Comment: @hpaulj i tried but didnot get as i am new to this python

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your exampe a combination of `open` with `readlines` and `split` with two whitespaces is doing the job.

```
# Using readlines()
file1 = open('input.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
  
count = 0
# Strips the newline character
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i==0:
        continue
    a,b,c,d = line.split(' '*3)
    print(f'In line {i} a is {a}, b is {b}, c is {c} and d is {d}.')
```

This is the output:

```
In line 1 a is sdt, b is  2.5, c is  3.5 and d is  1
In line 2 a is tyu, b is  2.8, c is  7.5 and d is  5
```

If you have more than 4 columns, you can use `split()` and apply this to one variable. This will be a list and you can select the items by zero-based counting.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo. I edited the answer.

Comment: it doesnot work if i have more columns of values

Comment: it also doesnot work what I expected

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: a should be  sdt and secondly tyu, it also prints nms

Comment: does the space creates problem here

Comment: I was counting 2. If there are three, you can adapt this.

Comment: `np.loadtxt` can handle files like this correctly.  You don't need to work with the base `readlines` (but you can if you want).

Comment: it doesnot work for this kind of line   ntw   stn   chn   loc   stla     stlo    evla    evlo   evdp
MN    XXX   YYY   00    22.252   22.585  33.258  75.533  5.5

Comment: @mosc9575 it doesnot work if i have more columns i donot know there might be some space problem

Comment: What do you mean with "space problems". You can do `split_list = split(' '*3)` and select the 1st item by `split_list[0]` and the n-th item by `split_list[n-1]`. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) for more details. If you have a specific use case, you could try to update you question, to make helping you easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [244]: cat test.csv
nms   val   pet  dzl
sdt   2.5   3.5   1
tyu   2.8   7.5   5
```

An easy way to load a csv is with pandas - I use the `engine` and `sep` to handle the white space separator (rather than the default comma):

```
In [245]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s+', engine='python')
In [246]: df
Out[246]: 
   nms  val  pet  dzl
0  sdt  2.5  3.5    1
1  tyu  2.8  7.5    5
```

Since you tagged dataframe and pandas, I'll assume you can take it from there.

`genfromtxt` can read it as well, but for strings that aren't floats it inserts a `nan`:

```
In [247]: data = np.genfromtxt('test.csv')
In [248]: data
Out[248]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, 2.5, 3.5, 1. ],
       [nan, 2.8, 7.5, 5. ]])
```

`np.loadtxt` given the same thing raises errors because it can't convert those strings to float.  That should be clear from the docs.

With a few more parameters you can get a nice structured array:

```
In [251]: data = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', dtype=None, names=True, encoding=None)
In [252]: data
Out[252]: 
array([('sdt', 2.5, 3.5, 1), ('tyu', 2.8, 7.5, 5)],
      dtype=[('nms', '<U3'), ('val', '<f8'), ('pet', '<f8'), ('dzl', '<i8')])
```

`data['val']` gives all the `val` column.  Or you can iterate on the rows with:

```
In [258]: for row in data:
     ...:     print(row)
     ...: 
('sdt', 2.5, 3.5, 1)
('tyu', 2.8, 7.5, 5)
```

A similar structured array from `loadtxt`:

```
In [262]: data = np.loadtxt('test.csv', dtype='str,f,f,i', skiprows=1,encoding=None)
In [263]: data
Out[263]: 
array([('', 2.5, 3.5, 1), ('', 2.8, 7.5, 5)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

With base `readlines` you can get a list of strings for each row, and parse those as you want:

```
In [264]: with open('test.csv','r') as f: lines = f.readlines()
In [265]: lines
Out[265]: ['nms   val   pet  dzl\n', 'sdt   2.5   3.5   1\n', 'tyu   2.8   7.5   5\n']
In [266]: lines[1]
Out[266]: 'sdt   2.5   3.5   1\n'
In [267]: lines[1].split()
Out[267]: ['sdt', '2.5', '3.5', '1']
In [268]: a,b,c,d = lines[1].split()
In [269]: b
Out[269]: '2.5'
```